# Nest headings properly (H1 > H2 > H3) in HTML?

Tags: html

**CSS :-**

```
  #sidebar .sidelink h6{
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding-left: 22px;
        padding-top: 9px;
        color: #f1f1f1;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

**Html :-**

```
<div class="sidelink">
<h6 class="side-title">
             Our Products
</h6>
</div>
```

When I try to validate the above code. I got a error "Nest headings properly (H1 > H2 > H3)"

How to Solve This?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means start your headings with h1, then do h2,h3,etc. for hierarchy purposes.

h1 headers at the top level
h2 headers at 2nd etc.

like an indented list has levels.

Should just be a warning, though not an error.

```
<h1>top level</h1>
<h2>2nd level</h1>
<h3>3rd level</h3>
<h2>second level again</h2>
<h3>3rd level</h3>
<h6>3rd to 6th should be fine after 2nd</h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.sidelink h6{
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding-left: 22px;
        padding-top: 9px;
        color: #f1f1f1;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Lose the wrapper, I don't see it in your example, and you can lose the class on the h6 as you're using inheritance to select it instead of the class.